# How should I understand the following passage simply?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

How should I understand the following passage simply?

What does 'take the character' mean?

Could you paraphrase this passage in simple type?

Should I take this sentence as: 'Prayers take the character of private communications with God, selfish bargaining with God'?

The passage:

> Prayers take the character of private communications, selfish
> bargaining with God. It seeks for objects of earthly ambitions and
> inflames the sense of self. Meditation on the other hand is self-
> change.

Source: Buddhism in a Nutshell
P. 22
By Nadara thera

Comment: In your context, ***take the character*** is just a fancy way of saying ***are***. As ever, this text is completely  unsuitable for learning current English. I assume the syntax error of coupling plural ***prayers*** in the first sentence with singular ***it*** in the second, is OP's copying error. But if not, that's just further evidence of the text being unsuitable.

Comment: Thanks @fumble Fingers, it is not 'copying error'. I took it from its original page using 'copy and paste'.

Comment: The text is obviously a translation. Perhaps in the *original* language, "prayers" and/or "private communications" are singular nouns, OR it's syntactically possible for "it" to refer back to singular "selfish bargaining with God". But singular "it" doesn't work for the start of the second sentence in English, whatever it's supposed to refer back to. But I'd say @Kate's "silent" replacement of ***prayers*** with ***prayer*** is what you *should* have been reading.

Answer (score 1):

*Take the character of* is just a fancy way of saying *be/become like.*

The author is saying that prayer is about asking God for things you want for yourself. (It doesn't have to be, but there is a popular idea that that's all it is.)

Answer (score 0):

*"Take the character of"* means nearly the same thing as *"assume the form of"* or *"take the form of."*

In other words, the statement is suggesting that prayers amount to, or are equivalent to, *"private communications, selfish bargaining with God."*

Comment: Thanks you very much, Biblasia.